# How to get first 3 character of month name in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am creating my WordPress theme...
This way I can get the month when the post was published as a string:

```
<?php the_time('j'); ?>
```

Now I need only the first 3 characters of this string.

For example: JANUARY should be JAN, APRIL should be APR...

Answer (score 0):

"M  - Textual three letters Jan - Dec"

https://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time

In that case:

```
<?php the_time('M'); ?>
```

Will be ok.

Comment: And about capital letters:
- php:
    strtoupper()
- css:
    text-transform: capitalize;